# Error on uploading mutlipart data from Javascript to S3 using pre singed url from .net core API

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, amazon-s3, axios

I am generating the pre-signed URL using the below code in .NET(API/Backend).

```
var preSignedUrlRequest = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Key = keyName,
    UploadId = data.UploadID,
    PartNumber = data.PartNumber,
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1440),
    //Protocol = (Protocol.HTTPS),
    Verb = HttpVerb.PUT
    //ContentType = data.ContentType,

};
var url = s3Client.GetPreSignedURL(preSignedUrlRequest);
```

And send back to the frontend (Javascript file run at http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html) to upload file bytes directly to S3.

```
for (let index = 1; index < NUM_CHUNKS + 1; index++) {
    start = (index - 1) * FILE_CHUNK_SIZE
    end = (index) * FILE_CHUNK_SIZE
    blob = (index < NUM_CHUNKS) ? state.selectedFile.slice(start, end) : state.selectedFile.slice(start)

    const sData = {
            fileName: state.fileName,
            partNumber: index,
            uploadID: state.uploadId,
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    let res = await axios.post(`${state.backendUrl}/FileUpload/GetUrlForEachPart`, sData);
    let presignedUrl = res.data;
    if(!presignedUrl) return;

    let uploadResp = axios.put(
        presignedUrl,
        blob
         , { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'}}
    );
    promisesArray.push(uploadResp)
}
```

But getting the following error:

```
<Error>
   <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
   <Message>
    The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
   </Message>
   <AWSAccessKeyId>
  SomeKey
   </AWSAccessKeyId>
   <StringToSign>
      PUT
      application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8
      1619642107
      /bucketname/profile_pictures/563131de-1359-4efb-b971-ad64ffffb424.jpg?partNumber=1&uploadId=fz8XMvcY7PRLLTq5TnF22oMEblJxq9cAgx8NnogKlU86W11DNeIVlvceWUICtTKAuUBafdY9UiguWHCDAEqKLFay6Mz8_DfFBaFCITfJdo3ronBL92xPHA9js02JY54v
    </StringToSign>
    <SignatureProvided>
      xEKWu7sASAVBvdT0fXtN+fMCg3k=
    </SignatureProvided>
    <StringToSignBytes>
      50 55 54 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 4d 44 35 0a 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 78 2d 77 77 77 2d 66 6f 
     </StringToSignBytes>
     <RequestId>AAKH5YH55KGG7ME4</RequestId>
     <HostId>8FbaBlqRefB1BWdqDkOvZbWijFr6RTUvO8olEiEkNnytXbA01FECI2bplM=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I am trying to fix it from yesterday and try many solutions of stackoverflow. But no luck.

If anyone figure out my mistake, it will be a great help.
Thanks

NB: there is no use with my credentials. I can upload the file bytes from backend without pre-signed url.